# Scala save array in ElasticSearch

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, hadoop

I have a field in my dataframe which contains a list of aggregated values that I turn to a JSON array string.
When I try to save my dataframe into ElasticSearch, I get this error :

> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: mapper_parsing_exception: object mapping for [userSegments] tried to parse field [userSegments] as object, but found a concrete value

Here is an example of my column userSegments

```
{{"segmentID":"c42cc7d7-b2c6-44fa-bc1e-edd8854f2590","segmentName":"Women"},{"segmentID":"cb5b0e7b-cf7c-4395-82a3-4076075d3e6d","segmentName":"Mode"}}
```

Here is my index mapping :

```
"userSegments": {
          "properties": { 
           "segmentID": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
                }
            },           
            "segmentName": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I have checked and all my records lookalike the one provided or have a null, so there are no mix of data type provided to ES.

Any idea on how I can go over this issue?

Thanks a lot
Matthieu

Comment: Has the solution not worked ?

Answer (score 0):

With those mappings, this should work:

```json
PUT /<your-index>/_doc/doc-1
{
  "userSegments": [
    {
      "segmentID": "c42cc7d7-b2c6-44fa-bc1e-edd8854f2590",
      "segmentName": "Women"
    },
    {
      "segmentID": "cb5b0e7b-cf7c-4395-82a3-4076075d3e6d",
      "segmentName": "Mode"
    }
  ]
}
```

So you need to check whether the code that takes your data frame and builds the Elastic Query is doing something different.

Your error strongly suggests that your code is parsing the data into a string:

```json
PUT /<your-index>/_doc/doc-2
{
  "userSegments": """[{
      "segmentID": "c42cc7d7-b2c6-44fa-bc1e-edd8854f2590",
      "segmentName": "Women"
    },
    {
      "segmentID": "cb5b0e7b-cf7c-4395-82a3-4076075d3e6d",
      "segmentName": "Mode"
    }]"""
}
```

You should try to construct an actual JSON array from your data as the my first shows.